# Arahants and exersise

Tags: lay-buddhism, buddha, arahant, wheel-of-dhamma

Q:

Would an arahant get physically exausted if he/she was to exersise, like if they were to run 5 miles? Would this in anyway shake their mind?

Answer (score 1):

## Buddha's mind is unshakable. But they still get tired and has to rest.

"Ananda, speak to the Kapilavatthu Sakyans about the person who follows the practice for one in training. [2] My backaches. I will rest it."

https://www.accesstoinsight.org/tipitaka/mn/mn.053.than.html

Answer (score 0):

Arahants don't run. But they walk long distances.